# Word Vba Input Box to set Document Orientation - IF with OR

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my macro I want to prompt for the page Orientation -- P or p for portrait, L or l for landscape.

Here is what I developed.    It works - but want to know if there is a better/more efficient way to develop If statements for "OR" --- do I have to use a "nested" If??

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Orientation As String

  With Selection.PageSetup
        .LineNumbering.Active = False
        .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
        .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(8.5)
        .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(11)
        .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
        .SuppressEndnotes = False
        .MirrorMargins = False
        .TwoPagesOnOne = False
        .BookFoldPrinting = False
        .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
        .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
        .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
    End With


' set Orientation


    Orientation = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter P for Portriait, L for Landscape")

    If Orientation = "L" Then
        With Selection.PageSetup
              .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        End With
    ElseIf Orientation = "l" Then
        With Selection.PageSetup
              .Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
        End With
    Else
        With Selection.PageSetup
              .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure is there a better (more efficient) way to develop MS Word page orientation... I would not use `InputBox`, but if you want to use it i'd do something like this:

```
AskAgain:
    Orientation = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter P for Portriait, L for Landscape")

    Select Case UCase(Orientation) 
         Case "L"
            Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
         Case "P"
            Selection.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
         Case Else
            GoTo AskAgain
    End Select
```

To be honest... leave the decision to the user and do not prevent user to set page orientation from VBA code, but call print preview window. This is best way - in my opinion.

Comment: I thank you for your answer --- but what if the user enters a lowercase instead of uppercase?      Does this mean I need to have 4 CASE statements or 4 IF statements?

Comment: Have a look at `Select Case` statement... I'm using `UCase()` function which returns upper case. So you don't need to use 4 if statements.